# Split a string and convert one of the index as int

Tags: c#, string, split

I have the following code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string prueba = "Something_2.zip";
            int num;

            prueba = prueba.Split('.')[0];

            if (!prueba.Contains("_"))
            {
                prueba = prueba + "_";
            }
            else
            {
                //The code I want to try                    
            }                  
        }
```

The idea is that in the else I want to split the string after the `_` and convert it to int, I did this like

```
num = Convert.ToInt16(prueba.Split('_')[1]);
```

but can I cast the split? for example `num = (int)(prueba.Split('_')[1]);`
Is it possible to do it that way? Or I have to use the `Convert`?

Comment: @d.moncada yes, but It says I can't convert a string to int. So the only way is to use the Convert then?

Comment: Have you tried using Convert? What error are you getting then?

Comment: @Jorgel with Convert runs perfectly, but I wanted to make sure there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You Cannot cast string as integer, so you need to do some conversion:
>   I suggest you to use `Int.TryParse()` in this scenario.
>   Hence the else part will be like the following:

```
else
  {
     if(int.TryParse(prueba.Substring(prueba.LastIndexOf('_')),out num))
       {
         //proceed your code
       }
     else
       {
         //Throw error message
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the `string` to `int` like this:

```
var myInt = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(prueba.Split('_')[1], out myInt))
{
   // use myInt here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a string, so you'll have to parse it. You can use Convert.ToInt32, int.Parse, or int.TryParse to do so, like so:

```
var numString = prueba.Split('_')[1];
var numByConvert = Convert.ToInt32(numString);
var numByParse = int.Parse(numString);
int numByTryParse;
if(int.TryParse(numString, out numByTryParse))
    {/*Success, numByTryParse is populated with the numString's int value.*/}
else
    {/*Failure. You can handle the fact that it failed to parse now. numByTryParse will be 0 */}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string prueba = "Something_2.zip";

prueba = prueba.Split('.')[0];

int theValue = 0; // Also default value if no '_' is found

var index = prueba.LastIndexOf('_');
if(index >= 0)
    int.TryParse(prueba.Substring(index + 1), out theValue);

theValue.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and avoid all the string splitting logic. If you need an explanation of the regex I've used see https://regex101.com/r/fW9fX5/1

```
var num = -1; // set to default value that you intend to use when the string doesn't contain an underscore
var fileNamePattern = new Regex(@".*_(?<num>\d+)\..*");
var regexMatch = fileNamePattern.Match("Something_2.zip");
if (regexMatch.Success)
{
    int.TryParse(regexMatch.Groups["num"].Value, out num);
}
```